# NodeJS handling processing complex requests

Tags: node.js, timeout

I have situation in my NodeJS API where I need to handle complex request which usually takes about few seconds to process. Problem is when I'm doing load tests on this API call I'm starting to receive back Timeouts (but requests still been processed in background). How and what is best option to handle this situation? Should I increase timeout or do something else? Where I need to do that, on NodeJS side or maybe on Nginx side because I use Nginx as reverse proxy?

Comment: Sounds to me like nginx might be timing out but we don't have enough information about your specific situation.  Try to determine if nginx is timing out or your load test client or what.

Comment: I tried to turn off timeouts on Nginx. In this moment I'm configuring timeout on NodeJS side with res.setTimeout, and still I get Timeout and requests are being stacked and processed in background.

Comment: Show the test script/command and output please.

Comment: Show the code in the request handler please.  Is that blocking the Node process with some CPU intensive task?

Comment: Are you using Node cluster?

Comment: If it is a CPU intensive task, how many CPUs do you have in that machine/VM?

Comment: @JasonLivesay - I think you're going down the wrong direction.  The question is not about why the request takes as long as it does.  The question is how to prevent timeouts given how long the request takes.

Comment: It's CPU intensive task, and unfortunately needs to be, so I just need to find best way to handle timeouts. I think the best option is that I can setup timeout (for example on 1 min) and when that's happen, that NodeJS stop processing that request or something. I'm looking for best practice in this situation and how to achieve it.

Comment: @jfriend00 I was exploring a valid path in addition to the previous more obvious path that I started exploring. Do me a favor, please don't address me in any further comments on this site.

Comment: @JasonLivesay - It is clear from the latest comments that the OP is asking about how to control timeouts, not how to make their process run faster.  I'm not sure why you took such offense when I tried to point that out.